# ２つのディレクトリ構造の共通部分を計算するには？

Tags: shellscript, unix

`diff -r dir1 dir2` で、ディレクトリの構造的な diff を取得できますが、
逆に、ディレクトリの構造的な共通部分を知りたく成りました。

これは、どうやったら実現できますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-s` で、同じであったファイル情報が出力できることに気が付きました。

```
diff -rsq dir1 dir2
```